Does PieCloudDB support ARM architecture?
We are processing PoC now, since the underlying architecture has been converted from the original x86 system to the ARM system, I would like to know whether PieCloudDB can support the ARM system in addition to the x86 system?

PieCloudDB is compatible with ARM systems and can take full advantage of the ARM architecture. After testing, it has obtained Kunpeng 920 compatibility certification.
